# Does rendering/baking get rid of any Antialiasing ghosting?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal

I saw this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/gpc2hh/ghost_trail_motion_trail_removal/) where they describe an issue that I've been having where the machine struggles with calculating AA so it leaves a ghost trail.

I want to record the viewport and use these as videos so no real time calculations are needed.

Would this be solved by rendering/baking?

I did a quick render test but the issue was still there but maybe I missed something.

Before I go that route I wanted to know if it's possible.